# How to order groupBy items

Tags: c#, linq

Having this Linq query which returns grouping of 4 `DateTime`:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, QuoteSnapshotModel>> lista = (from q in quoteModeList
                                                              where q.QuoteTradeType == "Q"
                                                              select q).GroupBy(n => n.ExceriseDate);
```

How can I order the groups by `DateTime` and get only the first group?
meaning `**List<QuoteSnapshotModel>**`

Also, how can I get only the second `List<QuoteSnapshotModel>` (according to `DateTime`)

Comment: You can use [First()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) or [FirstOrDefault()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) when you want to get first group. And For only the second

Comment: You get only the second .[Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)(1).[Take(1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx);

Answer (score 0):

> How can I order the groups by DateTime

`.OrderBy(g => g.Key)` or `.OrderBy(g => g.First().ExerciseDate)`

> and get only the first group?

`.First()` (or `.FirstOrDefault()` if it's possible there are 0 groups)

> how can I get only the second List (according to DateTime)

`.Skip(1).Take(1)` or `.ElementAt(1)` or `.Skip(1).First()`

Putting it all together:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, QuoteSnapshotModel>> lista = ( 
    from q in quoteModeList
    where q.QuoteTradeType == "Q"
    select q
).GroupBy(n => n.ExerciseDate);

IList<QuoteSnapshotModel> firstQuote = lista.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Select(x => x.ToList()).FirstOrDefault();
IList<QuoteSnapshotModel> secondQuote = lista.OrderBy(x => x.Key).Skip(1).Select(x => x.ToList()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: sais cannot implicitly convert from IGrouping. I am trying to get result in a type of List<QuoteSnapshotModel)

Comment: @user829174 - IGrouping<TKey, TElement> is *also* an IEnumerable<TElement>. So calling .ToList on your IGrouping<DateTime, QuoteTradeModel> gives you an IList<QuoteTradeModel>. Updated code w/a Select(x => x.ToList()))

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You can use only the first group

```
List<QuoteSnapshotModel> list =quoteModeList.Where(x=>x.QuoteTradeType =="Q")
                                            .GroupBy(x => x.ExceriseDate)
                                            .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
                                            .FirstOrDefault().Select(x=>x.QuoteTradeType).ToList();
```

You can use only the second group

```
 List<QuoteSnapshotModel> list =quoteModeList.Where(x=>x.QuoteTradeType =="Q")
                                             .GroupBy(x => x.ExceriseDate)
                                             .OrderBy(x=>x.Key)
                                             .Skip(1).First().Select(x=>x.QuoteTradeType).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for this you have to create a `list<QuoteSnapshotModel`> within class `QuoteSnapshotModel`.

```
int record = 1;
   List<QuoteSnapshotModel> result =
                 quoteModeList
                .Where(x => x.QuoteTradeType == "Q")
                .GroupBy(x => x.ExceriseDate,
                (a, b) => new QuoteSnapshotModel
                {
                    ExceriseDate = a,
                    ListQuoteSnapshotModel = b.ToList()
                })
                .OrderByDescending(t => t.ExceriseDate)
                .Skip(record - 1).Take(1).ToList();
```